# Home compiled j2me java VM loops forever in FloatingDecimal.class constructor

Tags: java, java-me

I compiled Sun's j2me sources for a linux x64 machine. The only trouble I found till now is when executing `Double.toString()`. 
This method starts constructing a `FloatingDecimal` instance; then the kvm hangs, obviously in a forever loop. 
I think it may relate to endianess in the compilation, and forced somehow the corresponding manifest to little endian.

The compiled kvm which comes with the source tarball runs perfectly.

Could someone point me to a tool or document that allow me to find the error?
I tried with valgrind, at no luck.

TIA.
Regards